# Convert procedural code into class for Blobs

Tags: php, azure

So I have the following code that I built out that grabs some images from an Azure storage library:

```
$accountName = 'teststorageaccount';
$accountKey = '**';
$containerName = 'users';

$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName={$accountName};AccountKey={$accountKey}";
$blobClient = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

try {
    $blob_list = $blobClient->listBlobs($containerName);
    $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

    // Grab all the blob links
    foreach ($blobs as $blob) {
        echo $blob->getUrl() . "</br>";
    }
} catch(ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

Then I'm getting the following results back:

```
http://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/users/ABREUG.jpg
http://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/users/ABUKHADA.jpg
http://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/users/ACHANT.jpg
http://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/users/ACQUISTE.jpg
```

---

Now this is where I would need some help .. I'm practicing on building out everything in a class, and this is how far I've come:

```
class AzureStorage
{
    private $accountName;
    private $accountKey;
    private $containerName;

    public static function init()
    {
        return new AzureStorage([
            'accountName' => 'teststorageaccount',
            'accountKey' => '***',
            'containerName' => 'users',
        ]);
    }

    /**************************************************************************/

    public function __construct(array $data = [])
    {
        if (count($data) === 0) {
            return;
        }
        $this->load($data);
    }

    public function load(array $data) : void
    {
        if (isset($data['accountName'])) {
            $this->accountName = $data['accountName'];
        }
        if (isset($data['accountKey'])) {
            $this->accountKey = $data['accountKey'];
        }
        if (isset($data['containerName'])) {
            $this->containerName = $data['containerName'];
        }
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={$this->accountName};AccountKey={$this->accountKey}";
        $blobClient = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);

        return $blobClient;
    }

    public function getContainers() : array
    {
        $containers = $this->connect()->listContainers();
        return $containers->getContainers();
    }

    public function getBlobURLs()
    {
        try {
            $blob_list = $this->connect()->listBlobs($this->containerName);
            $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

            // Grab all the blob links
            foreach ($blobs as $blob) {
                echo $blob->getUrl() . "</br>";
            }
        } catch (ServiceException $e) {
            $code = $e->getCode();
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
            echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The problem**: How would I be able to use the try and catch inside the getBlobURLs method and then output the results? I'm unable to get results when calling it outside the class.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$test2 = new \AzureStorage\AzureStorage([
    'accountName' => 'teststorageaccount',
    'accountKey' => '***',
    'containerName' => 'users',
]);
```

Now if I call the following (I get an array of containers, which works perfectly):

```
$containers = $test2->getContainers();
//var_dump($containers);
```

But if I do the following (I get no results outputted back):

```
$blobs = $test2->getBlobURLs();
var_dump($blobs);
```

Does anyone know why I might not be getting the URLs back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a return statement in `getContainers` function but not in `getBlobURLs`.

```
public function getBlobURLs(){
    try {
        $blob_list = $this->connect()->listBlobs($this->containerName);
        $blobs = $blob_list->getBlobs();

        $blobUrls = [];
        // Grab all the blob links
        foreach ($blobs as $blob) {
            $blobUrls[] = $blob->getUrl();
        }
        return $blobUrls;
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Now if you want to display blob url list then

```
$blobs = $test2->getBlobURLs();

if($blobs === false){
   echo 'Error while getting blob urls.';
}
else{
    foreach($blobs as $blobUrl){
       echo $blobUrl . "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: so it looks like I'm still not getting any results back as nothing is displaying on my screen, the procedural way echos the links, does the return do the same?

Comment: no , return will send back data and it will be stored in `$blobs` variable. Then you can loop over it and display it

Comment: Thanks so much, this works! I selected as the main answer, please upvote me also if you think I did  great job explaining the problem.

Comment: One last question, if I wanted to grab `$blob->getName();` with `$blob->getUrl();` also, how would I do it in the same try catch?

Comment: you need to create two indexes in same array like `$blobUrls[] = ['url' => $blob->getUrl(), 'name' => $blob->getName()];` but then you need to modify your printing sytle too. If it works for you then fine, otherwise you can create a separate question for that.